Why do ggmagnify() zoomed-in insets are off-limit?
First, I am not very familiar with the R language and learn it. I use R4.31, RStudio , ggplot2 3.5.1, dplyr 1.1.4 and ggmagnify 0.4.1.
Second, most of my needs are plots so ggplot is very useful. This week-end, I played with the ggmagnify package and it gave weird displays.
With this code, I get a regular plot, as intended
install.packages("ggmagnify", repos = c("https://hughjonesd.r-universe.dev", 
                                        "https://cloud.r-project.org"))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmagnify)

starwars %>% 
  
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = mass,
                       y = height,
                       color = sex)) +
  
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE,
              method = "lm") +
  
  labs(x = "masse en kg",
       y = "taille en cm") +
  
  theme_bw() +
  
  geom_magnify(from = c(xmin = 0, xmax = 200, ymin = 50, ymax = 275),
               to = c(xmin = 500, xmax = 750, ymin = 50, ymax = 140))


So far, so good, but, when I try this code with a condition, the plot is not as intented:
starwars %>% 
  
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = mass,
                       y = height,
                       color = sex)) +
  
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE,
              method = "lm") +
  
  labs(x = "masse en kg",
       y = "taille en cm") +
  
  theme_bw() +
  
  geom_magnify(mapping = aes(from = sex == "female" & mass < 100),
               to = c(xmin = 500, xmax = 750, ymin = 50, ymax = 140),  
               zoom.size = 2)


Then, I tried to get a double zoom (zoom2 should be created from zoom1), to see what happens. The code :
starwars %>% 
  
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = mass,
                       y = height,
                       color = sex)) +
  
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE,
              method = "lm") +
  
  labs(x = "mass in kg",
       y = "height in cm") +
  
  theme_bw() +
  
  geom_magnify(mapping = aes(from = sex == "female" & mass < 100),
               to = c(xmin = 500, xmax = 750, ymin = 50, ymax = 140),  
               zoom.size = 2) +
  
  geom_magnify(from = c(xmin = 550, xmax = 700, ymin = 100, ymax = 125),
               to = c(xmin = 1000, xmax = 1250, ymin = 200, ymax = 250))


I do not understand 2 points:

why the small zoom windows are offset while the limits in the to= argument are within the axis limits?
why this code chunk

  geom_magnify(mapping = aes(from = sex == "female" & mass < 100),
               to = c(xmin = 500, xmax = 750, ymin = 50, ymax = 140))

gives the same result as this one ?
geom_magnify(mapping = aes(from = mass < 100),
               to = c(xmin = 500, xmax = 750, ymin = 50, ymax = 140))

Fixes I tried include:

changing the value or commenting out of the zoom.size = argument
remove NAs with drop_na(mass, height)
changing the values of from = and to =

Any help would be appreciated to get a better understanding of where and how I got wrong.
Have a nice day.

Concernign the first issue. It took me a second look before I realized that the limits of the y scale are different. In the first plot where you set from= as a vector of coordinates the limits account for the range you set via from= (i.e. the range is 50 to 275 (+ some expansion)), whereas in the second plot where you use the from aes the limits are based on the range of the data (which is range(starwars$height, na.rm = TRUE) = c(66, 264)), i.e. in the second plot 50 is outside of the limits an the magnified plot gets clipped off.

Ok, thank you very much, I scratched my head for an embarrassing long time without thinking of that angle! I see it know, a simple layer ylim(0, 250) or coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 250)) solved this 1st problem.
